# How to find the minimum value of signal?

Tags: matlab, minimum

I have the message signal of `s(t)` and I know the code of finding the minimum of signal `min(s)`.

If `t > 2`, `s(t)` will be equal to `0`.

How can I find the minimum value of `s(t)` within `2` second?

I need to plot conventional AM signal, I have message signal `s(t)` and module signal, and the `s(t)` is equal to `0` when `t > 2`, now I need to calculate the minimum value of `s(t)` for calculating the Ac value.

Comment: Can you explain more? and show what you did

Comment: Does matlab have built-in functions?  I would be looking for data analysis library with a floor function that can be applied over a range.  floor(s,tbegin,tend) sort of thing.  Also, if you need to code it, you'll want to clarify whether this is a continuous function or discrete.

Comment: @Bhbf i need to plot conventional AM signal, i have message signal s(t) and module signal, and the s(t) is equal to 0 when t > 2, now i need to calculate the minimum value of s(t) for calculating the Ac value. Plz

Comment: @Xalorous continuous function, and the detail in comment. Plz

Comment: I suggest that you edit the original question to add the details from the comment into the question.  It would be useful if you added code that you have tried including what output you expected and what you got instead.

Comment: @Xalorous i edited the question already, i have no idea how to calculate. Plz

Comment: I would add the code that generates your signal to your question to allow everyone to know how your signal is sampled/configured.  The answer below is a correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you want to restrict the space in which you are searching for the minimum. You can use logical indexing to do this.

```
timevector = 1:10000; %in ms
signal = randi(1000, 10000, 1);
signal(2000:10000) = 0;

log_signal = timevector < 2000;
constrained_signal = signal(log_signal);
minimum = min(constrained_signal);
```